# Which file to put HTTP Response in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby, http

I'm working on my first Ruby application. I would like to get the HTTP Response code for a get request. The basic format seems to be something like below. However since I'm very new to Ruby, I don't know which file this code should go in. Does it go in my 'def index' method in the Controller? In the index.html.erb file itself? I know it's a super basic question but I'm a bit lost. Thanks, for any help

```
require "net/http"

require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/users")

# Shortcut
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

# Will print response.body
Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)

# Full
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))`
```

Comment: 'net/http' is for making HTTP requests. Ruby on Rails is for receiving them.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ruby!

After doing `response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)`. You can simply query the response object for it's code:

`response.code` that will print "200" or whatever code you get.

A common way to find out new things in Ruby is to ask an object for it's methods: `response.methods` shows `:code`, that's how I knew. I hope this tip helps you!

**EDIT**: It seems I misunderstood your question. If you are looking for the response code of a GET request, this is how you get it. If you are trying to run your newly created Rails app, simply go to the browser and type that URL once you have your rails server running locally.

Comment: Thanks for the response(pun intended)! Does the response code for the GET request go in my controller file? In this case 'users_controller.rb'? I know how to run the app on my local host, just not which file to put the http response.

Comment: No, this same http request can be done just by visiting http://localhost:3000/ in your browser. Are you trying to display the response code of a page in a second page? Tell us more on what the end goal is, what have you done in you rails app?

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. Thanks for taking some time to help me!

Comment: Please share your answer with the community, that's how others learn from everybody's previous experiences.